# Alternative SilkTest IDE

Tags: ide, silktest

Coming from Eclipse, there are many features that simply do not exist in the SilkTest IDE.

My question is this:

Is there an alternative IDE to SilkTest that I could use to maintain our SilkTest scripts? Something that can offer some of the power that Eclipse and many other mainstream IDEs bring to the table?

Some of the power I'm referring to is:

- Outline functionality
- Referencing/Call Hierarchy
- Formatter
- Context based searching (function call over a variable name)
- Declaration/Definition links

If the answer is "No", that's acceptable and is what I expect, but I will wait for a short time to give others the opportunity to answer. Additionally, we have the 2009 license of SilkTest. If these features are available in newer versions of the IDE, that's also an acceptable answer.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For 4Test (SilkTest's classic scripting language) the answer is 'No'.

However, for some time there are Silk4J and Silk4Net around, which allow you to create your test scripts in either Eclipse or Visual Studio, using Java or a .Net language. You can then use all the features the IDEs provide.

Note:
I work for Borland on the SilkTest team, so my answers are probably biased.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, this is what I had figured. Given that you are so directly involved in the software, I would imagine you would know best as to whether there were alternatives.